# How to convert a number into a format which will be separated by comma's by position in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
declare
a number

begin 

  a:=10000

  dbms_put_line(a)
end:
```

I want to get my output as 10,000.Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select rtrim(to_char(10000, 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''), '.')   from dual
```

the optional third NLS argument to the to_char() function to set the G and D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(to_char(a,'99,99,99,999')) ;
end;
```